# how to do a relative import from subpackage to top folder workdirectory with python 3.75?

Tags: python, import, relative-import

```
Project_folder
│
├───Tests
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   │
│   ├───features
│   │       smallcircle.feature
│   │
│   ├───steps_tests
│   │   │   test_smallcircle.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   __init__.py
│   a.py
```

I'm triying to make a relative import from **test_smallcircle.py** to **a.py** as shown bellow

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname("C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\solution\\a.py"))
from a import smallest_circle # JUST HERE
from pytest_bdd import (
    given,
    scenario,
    then,
    when,
)
import pytest_bdd
from functools import partial
```

but it shows the next error

```
Unable to import 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a relative import, you need to go up a level:

```
from ..a import smallest_circle
```

Comment: still unable to import, but now saying this : ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it was at the absulte path `C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\solution\\a.py`
that I append to the sys.path variable, the absolute path should be to the directory, not to the target file, so the solution was replacing it for `C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Desktop\\solution`